# Diff between Library and WEB-INF/Lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am new to Using Eclipse,

I wanted to know the difference between Library folder and web-Inf/lib folder during Runtime

Problem:
           I am using JSTL ,when i added the JSTL jar files in Library folder,it still showed errors in my JSP(during runtime),whereas after adding in WEB-INf/lib folder ,the errors got rectified.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember, Library folder is used by Eclipse to compile your software (jdk) but WEB-INF/lib contains all librairies you need to execute your software at runtime.